# What variables are in scope in a callback function?

Tags: javascript, callback

```
getTodos(function(){
    console.log(todos)
});


function getTodos(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        const todos = [{title:"Walk the dog"},{title:"Feed the cat"}];
        callback();
    },1000);
};
```

I thought the callback function when executed after 1 sec will be able to see the todo const. But the interpreter tells me ***todos is not defined***

Am i missing something here?

To add more knowledge that i learnt from a fellow programmer here: "Parent scope is not where its *called* but where its *defined*"

```
var todos = [{title:"Curb the dog"},{title:"Tickle the cat"}]
var cb = function(){
    console.log(todos);
}
getTodos(cb);


function getTodos(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        const todos = [{title:"Walk the dog"},{title:"Feed the cat"}];
        callback();
    },1000);
};
```

Comment: See [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500431/1529630)

Comment: JavaScript has [lexical scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)#Lexical_scoping). Your example would probably work if JavaScript had *dynamic scope*, but it doesn't (and I believe very few languages do).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course it is undefined because

```
function(){
    console.log(todos)
}
```

is outside of the scope of the `getTodos` function.

To fix it, you can pass `todos` into the callback function:

```
getTodos(function(todos){
    console.log(todos)
});

function getTodos(callback) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        var todos = [{title:"Walk the dog"},{title:"Feed the cat"}];
        callback(todos);
    }, 1000);
}
```

---

Protip: `const todos` *doesn't* mean the value in `todos` is constant and cannot be changed.

Quick check:

```
const list = ["Apple", "Banana"];
list[2] = "Coffee Beans";
list;                     // ["Apple", "Banana", "Coffee Beans"]

list.splice(0,1);
list;                     // ["Banana", "Coffee Beans"]

list = "something else";  // Uncaught TypeError
```

In other words, `todos` is a constant reference but that's probably not what you thought it was.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I sort of assumed that console.log(todos) when unable to find todos in the functional scope will look for it in the parent scope

Comment: Ditto.  I've never used callbacks quite this way before.  Thanks for sharing the technique.

Comment: @user1677501: It does. The parent scope is not where the function is *called* but where it is *defined*, because of **lexical scope**.